# How to get list of instagram follower with angular from url?

Tags: angularjs, api, instagram-api

Instagram has closed some API accesses. I can't access the followers list using API. I tried to use the url to access the list of followers. Didn't work.

My code:

```
$http.get('https://www.instagram.com/hakanhyemez/followers').then(function (response) {
           $scope.html = response.data;
        });
```

Runtime Url:

> Request URL:
>   https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/hakanhyemez/followers/

I actually login for instagram. For this reason I can not access list. How can i access? Is there a way?

Comment: i guess your endpoint is wrong

Comment: Hi  Sajeetharan, what endpoint are you talking about?

Comment: to get the followers count

Comment: I don't want to get count of followers. I want to get a list of followers.